# Error in first Android app in Eclipse juno

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just started a video tutorial for Android Development and I am working on Eclipse Juno. I created a first android app with the help of the video and Google, but the code have some extra lines which are not included in the video.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;
import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;


public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

This is the code that came in my workspace. It also shows error. It says "R cannot be resolved to a variable" and it suggests to import R.

Please give me suggestions as to how I can fix this. I tried to remove the onCreateOptionsMenu and import R. Then it suggests to change to "R.layout.activity_list_item"from "R.layout.activity_main".

Help!
Thanks.

Comment: Please do not import android.R; remove it

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22R+cannot+be+resolved+to+a+variable%22&rlz=1C1SAVC_enIN511IN512&oq=%22R+cannot+be+resolved+to+a+variable%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.434j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 shows so many results for this same problem please do some research before posting the question

Answer (score 0):

You are importing this import android.R; You should remove the same and clean and build your project.

If you have errors in your resource files R.java will not be generated. You should not import android.R; since your app will refer to resources in android framework rather then your project resource files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake.Do not import  android.R just remove the import ,clean and build

In Eclipse go to project and click on clean and then click on build.The project R file will be generated.

Comment: I also tried doing that before. But after that it gives a new error to change "layout.activity_main" to "activity_list_items".

Comment: Also, for the onCreateOptionsMenu method, there is another error for "R.menu.main, menu", here it says main is not resolves cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: check whether the layout file exist or not  if exist means check for error in the layout file.Remove the oncreateoptionmenu method  and try

Comment: @AnanyaKadir check if you have any erros in your resource files. Check if R.java is getting generated

Comment: @AnanyaKadir Also check if you have updated adt to rev 22 and check if you have installed android sdk build tools from the android sdk manager.

Comment: @jegan_u the layout file exists and there is no error in any xml files. I removed the onCreateOptionsMenu method, but it still shows the error to the layout.activity_main to activity_list_items. Thanks.

Comment: @Raghunandan there is no error in the res file either and R.java file is not created in gen.
I reinstalled adt22 and the sdk tools, but does not resolve the problem.
Thanks.